# Select all sites in IIS manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, web-server, iis-7

I just import a IIS config with 50 sites.

I will delete all of these sites several times to make new tests.

Currently I just delete them one by one...

I have not found how to select all sites to remove them in one hit.

Comment: Is a scripted solution acceptable? If yes, which scripting language would you prefer to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
cd %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\
```

and then

```
appcmd list site /xml | appcmd delete site /in
```

To delete all of the sites, although I'm not sure.  If it works it would be faster.

Learn more about piping appcmd here:
http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2007/06/17/things-you-can-do-by-piping-appcmd-commands.aspx

Comment: Wow, this is really cool!

Comment: It works superbly, thanks! Do you know how to add a filter to delete everything except certain sites?

Comment: Filter on their names. I look on your link.

Comment: I found `appcmd list site /name:"$=mySite*"` to list sites starting with "mySite". Any idea to list sites not starting with"mySite" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IIS `appcmd` command to remove a site automatically like this:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd delete site "Website1"
```

You can repeat the command in a script to delete specific website names whenever you run the script.  Create a file called `DeleteSites.bat` and paste the following code inside:

```
@echo off
cd %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\

appcmd delete site "Website1"
appcmd delete site "Website2"
appcmd delete site "Website3"
appcmd delete site "Website4"
appcmd delete site "Website5"
```

Save the file, and then double-click it.  That should delete the websites listed every time you run the script.

[Here's a useful article on iis.net](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) about using the `appcmd` to automate a lot of IIS tasks.

Comment: It's pretty easy, thanks. Is there a way to retrieve the list of sites?

Comment: I think I'll delete this response.  Chris's answer is much better.

Comment: No need to delete your answer, it works too. :)

Comment: this a good way to have specific control over what sites get deleted vs the above which blows away them all.

Answer (score 1):

When installed on IIS 7.0 or later Web Deploy adds a context menu item to IIS manager called Deploy.

There are multiple actions available here one of which is the Delete action. There are two options depending on what node you have selected in IIS manager:

```
Web site :   Deploy >> Delete Web Site and Content
Application: Deploy >> Delete Application and Content
```

For more details...please check below link

http://blogs.iis.net/richma/archive/2010/07/03/deleting-iis-web-sites-applications-and-their-content-with-web-deploy.aspx